# How can I load a COM oject from a JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, com, interop, com-interop

I am developing a JSP application and am being forced to load a COM object. Can such a thing can be done?

If yes, how?

Answer (score 5):

It is possible using a COM bridge like [JACOB](http://danadler.com/jacob/).

JACOB is a JAVA-COM Bridge that allows you to call COM Automation components from Java. It uses JNI to make native calls into the COM and Win32 libraries.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use the COM object within the Java side of things (i.e. server), you will need something like [J-Integra](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/) or [JNI Wrapper](http://www.teamdev.com/jniwrapper/index.jsf). There are several open-source projects that can do similar things.

If you need the use a COM object on the client-side (i.e. browser), then it's no different than how you would do it using plain-ole HTML.